# Call function from python in C++

Tags: python, c++, pyinstaller, static-linking

I'm currently working on a project with a separate cli and gui. The gui part is written in C++ to keep the exectuable small. I compiled my python program with pyinstaller and need to call some functions from the C++ program.

Python part:

```
import configparser
def getconfig() -> list:
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read("config.ini")
    section1 = config["general"]
    section2 = section["section2"]
    return [section1, section2] #should be a list of dict?
```

Compiling it via pyinstaller --onefile --clean myprogram.py

What i would like to do in C++ is :

```
//please correct me if this is the wrong type, 
//i know i probably need to do a bit of parsing between python and C++ types

std::vector<std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>> > = myprogram.getconfig()
```

I just don't want to do the config parsing in C++ again, or would you recommend this as it's probably easier to call the compiled python binary?

This program just needs to run on linux, windows is not necessary.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If so please mark it as closed, or comment if my answer was of any help to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only planning to run on POSIX-compatible systems (ie. GNU/Linux), you could spawn a new process to run the Python script, e.g. using the C function `exec`. Example:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
        char* args[] = { "pythonscript.py", NULL };
        int t = execv("pythonscript.py", args);
        if(t < 0) printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 0;
}
```

And then in pythonscript.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("hello, world!")
```

This trick works with bash scripts as well.
The script must be executable though, so remember to run `chmod +x pythonscript.py`.

EDIT:
You will likely need to use pipes or other mechanisms for inter-process communication. (this is not my expertise!)

Comment: A short tutorial for a hands-on approach for handling pipes can be found here: https://github.com/kirkedal/compSys-e2020-pub/blob/master/material/201026_signals/pipes.c